# Script Src for bower_components when using Grunt and Http Server

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

In an angular project, I am having trouble linking to a library contained within Bower Components.  On my index.html page, I have the following

`<script src="../bower_components/angular-flash-alert/dist/angular-flash.min.js"></script>`

My index.html is within an app folder, with bower_components outside on the same level as 'app'

`--app
  --index.html
--bower_components`

I am serving up using http-server within grunt, and wonder if grunt is the issue.  I have come across some people with similar issues with express, however no definite answer for how to set the path correctly.

Within my gruntfile, the http server is set as the following.  I read someone saying that when served, bower components would be served within app folder, but I have tried that path too with no luck..

`'http-server': {
   1
   2   ¦ 'dev': {
   3   ¦ ¦ ¦ root: './app',
   4   ¦ ¦ ¦ port: 8080,
   5   ¦ ¦ ¦ host: "127.0.0.1",
   6   ¦ ¦ ¦ cache: 10,
   7   ¦ ¦ ¦ showDir : true,
   8   ¦ ¦ ¦ autoIndex: true,
   9   ¦ ¦ ¦ ext: "html",
  10   ¦ ¦ ¦ runInBackground: true,`

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats the error you're getting, can you copy it from the dev tools console?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your interest
```
[Thu, 04 Feb 2016 16:01:55 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular-flash-alert/dist/angular-flash.min.js" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: I'd probably say instead of trying to figure out the issue you should probably put you're bower components inside the App folder to avoid further issues going foward - you can use a .bowerrc json file - http://bower.io/docs/config/  It's generally a bad idea to have the root of you're project looking back levels in the url. If theres files in your bower_components that don't make sense in the App folder maybe look at setting up https://github.com/AndrewDryga/grunt-bower-installer to give you more control.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks @MikeMellor